# angular test, can't find variable : $scope

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I did read the angular official tutorial and launch test with success. But I tried to make test for a simple controller (when you click on button a boolean change), i have the following error : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $scope

controller :

```
siteLogic = angular.module('siteLogic', []);

siteLogic.controller('siteCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope, initMap) {
  $scope.addingSite=false;

  $scope.changeAddingSite = function(){
    $scope.addingSite= !$scope.addingSite;
  };
}]);
```

file for test :

```
  describe('$scope initialisation', function() {

    beforeEach(module('siteLogic'));

    describe('sets the addingSite at the inverse', function() {
      var scope, controller;


      beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
        //it's on the next line I have the error indication
        controller = $controller('siteCtrl', { $scope: scope }); 
      }));

      it('sets true if false', function() {
        scope.addingSite = false;
        scope.changeAddingSite();
        expect(scope.addingSite).toEqual(true);
      });

      it('sets false if true', function() {
        $scope.addingSite = true;
        $scope.changeAddingSite();
        expect($scope.addingSite).toEqual(false);
      });
    });
  });
```

karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '..',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'test/dep/angular-1.3.15/angular.js',
      'test/dep/angular-1.3.15/angular-resource.js',
      'test/dep/angular-1.3.15/angular-route.js',
      'test/dep/angular-1.3.15/angular-mocks.js',
      'lib/map/public/angular/*.js',
      'test/map/*.js'
    ],
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS']
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second group of test change `$scope` to `scope`

```
  it('sets false if true', function() {
    $scope.addingSite = true; // there is no $scope
    $scope.changeAddingSite();
    expect($scope.addingSite).toEqual(false);
  });
```

```js
var siteLogic = angular.module('siteLogic', []);

siteLogic.controller('siteCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.addingSite=false;

  $scope.changeAddingSite = function(){
    $scope.addingSite= !$scope.addingSite;
  };
}]);

describe('$scope initialisation', function() {

    beforeEach(module('siteLogic'));

    describe('sets the addingSite at the inverse', function() {
      var scope, controller;


      beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
        //it's on the next line I have the error indication
        controller = $controller('siteCtrl', { $scope: scope }); 
      }));

      it('sets true if false', function() {
        scope.addingSite = false;
        scope.changeAddingSite();
        expect(scope.addingSite).toEqual(true);
      });

      it('sets false if true', function() {
        scope.addingSite = true;
        scope.changeAddingSite();
        expect(scope.addingSite).toEqual(false);
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="http://safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error stay the same.But I think you have right. The '$' is 
a code artifact of other solution i have try :
change var scope for var $scope
change scope = $rootScope.$new(); to scope ={}

but I don't understand my error

Comment: Thanks, it's work in a html page. I will continue to try launch with node and karma when i will have more time.

Comment: @Valtena you must check what files and witch order are loaded by Karma